# What's a field tip?

Tags: gear, archery

Of course I know that it's an arrowhead to shoot on targets with. However, I wonder how it's exactly defined.

So, what (exactly) is a field tip?

Comment: Like [on a raga tip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gXCN1DhHTZA)? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be surprising that this question is not as "simple" as it seems. As already stated a field tip is of course there to do target shooting. The crux is that not every "target arrowhead" is automatically a field tip.

However, this kind of tip is defined through it's form. It has a pretty pointy conical shape:

[image: Field tip]

It's often preferred to practice for the hunt. The reasons for this are pretty subjective in my opinion (and I doubt them) and that's why I don't cover them here.

### Overview

[image: Some tips]

> Field points are similar to target points and have a distinct
>   shoulder, so that missed outdoor shots do not become as stuck in
>   obstacles such as tree stumps. They are also used for shooting
>   practice by hunters, by offering similar flight characteristics and
>   weights as broadheads, without getting lodged in target materials and
>   causing excessive damage upon removal.